# How to use goog.webgl in google closure library

Tags: javascript, webgl, google-closure-library

I want to use WebGL with Google Closure Compiler (mostly for three-dimensional view). I looked in the library sources, but I found out that there are currenly one file in goog.webgl namespace, and it only does constant value definitions.

https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/webgl/webgl.js

So, how should this supposed to be used? Aren't there any sample codes I can refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @fileoverview Constants used by the WebGL rendering, including all of
>   the  * constants used from the WebGL context.  For example, instead of
>   using  * context.ARRAY_BUFFER, your code can use  *
>   goog.webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER. The benefits for doing this include allowing 
>   * the compiler to optimize your code so that the compiled code does not have to  * contain large strings to reference these properties,
>   and reducing runtime  * property access.

As the fileoverview mentions, goog.webgl is a list of constants specified by the webGl spec.

As far as I know, Google Closure doesn't have a layer for webGl per say.  I think your best bet would be to write something yourself or simply use a library like three.js in combination with Google Closure.